# Convolution of circular densities

Tags: distributions, convolution

I have two distributions. One is a delta function which is non-zero on a circle at radius 1, the other is filled circle of the same radius.

When I calculate their convolution I get something very unintuitive, not least because I would expect the result to be circularly symmetric.

Can someone explain what is going on here?

Here's the code, image of the evaluated cell below (10.3)

```
f[x_, y_] = DiracDelta[x^2 + y^2 - 1]
g[x_, y_] = UnitStep[1 - (x^2 + y^2)]
h[x_, y_] = Convolve[f[x, y], g[x, y], {x, y}, {p, q}] /. {p -> x, q -> y}

ContourPlot[f[x, y], {x, -1.5, 1.5}, {y, -1.5, 1.5}]
ContourPlot[g[x, y], {x, -1.5, 1.5}, {y, -1.5, 1.5}]
ContourPlot[h[x, y], {x, -1.5, 1.5}, {y, -1.5, 1.5}]
```

[image]